# localhost redirect to live url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have setup wp_options, wp-Posts, wp-postmeta, for the local server link also tried to configure the wp-config file with below mentioned code.

`define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/business' );

define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://localhost/business' );`

But still while aproaching the local url it automatically redirecting to live website link.

Comment: Wordpress keeps the url of where it was installed in its database in varous places. But there are docs on [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) that tell you how to deal with this.

Comment: I solved the problem that issue was not mentioned in the links you as you linked while negative marking. It was an (issue of .htaccess file's redirecting rule). My problem was different then the cases explained in the stack links.

Comment: Great, would be useful to see the `.htaccess` file in the question

Answer (score 0):

change site_url in database in wp_options

go to phpmyadmin->database->wp_options->site_url

Comment: Links are changed for all the realted tables in the database. But still facing the prob